# Snapshot isolation in SQL / code blocking reads

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactionscope, isolation-level

I suspect I don't understand fully what's going on or something weird is happening. (The first case is more likely I guess.)

The big picture:

- I'm trying to have a web-service perform certain operations asynchronously as they can be time consuming and I don't want the client to wait for the operations to finish (just query for the results every now and again to see the operation is done).
- The async code is wrapped in a transaction - in case something goes wrong, I want to be able to rollback any changes.
- Unfortunately the last step of the async code is to call a DIFFERENT service which queries the same database.
- Despite wrapping the whole thing in a Snapshot transaction, the last step fails as the service cannot read from the database.
- For that matter, while the async operation is underway I cannot perform a simple SELECT statements from the database either.

Here's a sample of the code which I'm currently using to test out the transactions (using Entity Framework 5 model first):

```
        using (var transaction = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope(System.Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, new System.Transactions.TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Snapshot }))
        {
            var db = new DataModelContainer();
            Log test = new Log();
            test.Message = "TEST";
            test.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
            test.Details = "asd";
            test.Type = "test";
            test.StackTrace = "asd";
            db.LogSet.Add(test);
            db.SaveChanges();
            using (var suppressed = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope(System.Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
            {
                var newDb = new DataModelContainer();
                var log = newDb.LogSet.ToArray();  //deadlock here... WHY?
            }
            test = db.LogSet.Where(l => l.Message == "TEST").Single();
            db.LogSet.Remove(test);
            db.SaveChanges();
            transaction.Complete();
        }
```

The code creates a simple Log entry in the database (yeah, I'm playing around at the moment so the values are rubbish). I've set the SQL database to allow snapshot isolation, and to my knowledge reads should still be permitted (these are being tested in this code by using a new, suppressed transaction and a new `DataModelContainer`). However, I cannot query the `LogSet` in the suppressed transaction or in SQL Management Studio - the whole table is locked!

So... why? Why is it locked if the transaction scope is defined as such? I've also tried other isolation levels (like `ReadUncommited`) and I still cannot query the table.

Could someone please provide an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: is snapshot isolation enabled in your DB? "Snapshot isolation must be enabled by setting the ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON database option before it is used in transactions"

Comment: @Moho Yes, it is. *I've set the SQL database to allow snapshot isolation*. Anyway, the problem persists when using OTHER isolation modes (less restrictive than `Serializable`), like `ReadUncommited`, and this one doesn't even need snapshot isolation enabled on the SQL server!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS, set your current isolation level to `SNAPSHOT` and see if that corrects your problem - it's probably set to `READ COMMITTED` and would therefore still block due to pending updates.

Update:

You can allow `READ COMMITTED` to access versioned rows DB-wide by altering the following option (and avoiding having to constantly set the current isolation level to `SNAPSHOT`):

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

Comment: It feels as if the isolation level setting in C# isn't being used at all. Snapshot isolation is just an extreme example where locking shouldn't occur, but the problem is with other isolation levels as well. Check the updated C# code - I don't need to use SSMS to perform the tests at this point. Also, setting `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` is a partial solution - as stated, it doesn't explain why the transaction isolation isn't correctly set (if it's set at all).

Comment: what your other sessions' isolation levels are DOES matter as I stated in the solution.  If you're set at `READ COMMITTED` - it will lock until you commit the changes.  That's the whole purpose of the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` setting - to prevent blocking while waiting for a `SNAPSHOT` commit

Comment: Ahh, I think I see what the issue is. I was under the impression that I need to explicitly open a transaction (when performing a simple SELECT SSMS query, for example).